# Working with date php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am making a reservation module in php

but facing a problem on fetching data i was store a date in d/m/y format..

I want to show upcoming and past reservations for upcoming i was use this query

```
$cdate = date('d/m/y');
$r = "select * from reservations WHERE uid = $uid AND rdate < '$cdate'";
```

its working but when the date is more then 10 it;s goes to past reservation i don;t know same thing in in past if date is less then 10 it;s showing in upcoming section....

if you will that will very appropriated..

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: " date is more then 10" what does that mean, can you give concrete real data examples of what you have in the db and what you want to select

Comment: mysql uses yyyy-mm-dd not d/m/y....if you stored as just text, obviously sorting as if it were a date won't work without conversion

Comment: i was convert the date as well  date('d/m/y').. when i echo this date it will show perfectly as i stored in db

Comment: @Dagon its  not working correctly.......

Comment: You never answered the question of what a date being more or less than 10 means

Comment: @developerwjk For example: reservation is on 11/3/2015 this this will goes to past reservation section and if Reservation date is 09/3/2015 this will show on upcoming section...